# Oracle11G Sql: Computing mathematical operations using function?

Tags: oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G sql and I want to calculate the Total_price which which means **quantity*unit_price**. How to do that by creating function for the columun 
**Total_price**?

Because Experts are there and they can help me.

here is my table attributes with their corresponding data

```
Table: ITEM

item_id    item_name      quantity    unit_price    Total_price  
    -------------------------------------------------------------
 1001       soap         5              $10            
 1002       Omo          2              $15        
 1003       Perfume      1              $52
 1004       Socks        3              $7
 1005       Tooth Brush  2              $5
```

I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_ammount_fn
RETURN number (10,2);
IS 
Total_amount number(10,2); 
BEGIN 
SELECT Quantity, Rate_per_unit, Total_amount
FROM purchase;
Total_amount=Quantity*Rate_per_unit;
RETURN Total_amount;
END;
/
```

finally:

```
Warning: Function is created with compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using 11g will suggest that you declare Total Price as a **Virtual Column** in your table ITEM. You can use the below syntax for column

```
          Total_Price NUMBER(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (quantity*unit_price)
```

You can get more details of the Virtual Functions [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php)

If you want to do it with a PL/SQL construct, then suggest that you use a procedure, it should be like :

```
         CREATE OR REPLACE procedure total_ammount_p  
         IS 
         Begin
         Update  item set total_price = unit_price*quantity;
         commit;
         END;
        /
```

Of the two, it will be better to use Virtual Column based approach

Hope is Helps

Vishad